# Google Javascript Custom Search API: Search images by image url

Tags: javascript, api

I'm have tried to search image by phrase and it's working, but i need to search images by url.
I need to find same image, but with larger size.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSON/Atom Custom Search API Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
      function hndlr(response) {
          console.log(response);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={your_developer_key_here}&cx={your_engine_id_here}&q=http://i.ytimg.com/vi/gonBdNO7VbY/hqdefault.jpg&callback=hndlr&imgSize=large&searchType=image">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sorry can't provide dev key, because it has 100 queries limit per day.

There is testing form at the bottom:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list?hl=ru

I was trying to see what parameter is passed via google image search form.

It's image_url=http://i.ytimg.com/vi/gonBdNO7VbY/hqdefault.jpg , but adding that to api request doesn't give any results.

Is it possible to do such a thing?

Comment: It seems it's actually not supported yet... Anyway I may be wrong, so i keep it opened.

Comment: i have this question too..did you find a way to search images by image url with custom search api?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sniffing an Android app to find API URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778072/sniffing-an-android-app-to-find-api-url)