# Google Custom Search API Search Image by Image URL

Tags: api, search

I am working on an application which will have an option for users to upload images. Once uploaded, the application will show other images from the web which look exactly similar, whether or not of the same size.

For this, I will create a temporary URL for the image so that I could provide Google custom search API the URL of the image. I would expect in response, URL's of images that are exactly the same or similar to it, perhaps in JSON format.

I did find a similar question posted in January. Till then Google did not support anything like this, apparently:

[Google Javascript Custom Search API: Search images by image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298398/google-javascript-custom-search-api-search-images-by-image-url)

One can also simply do:

http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?site=search&image_url={Image URL}

Since that is not part of an official API, it may not be right to use this method.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the answer quite simply is TinEye Commercial API https://api.tineye.com/welcome. I was looking in the wrong place I guess, I did not have any luck with Google Custom Search API.

Comment: That's a shame. I looked into TinEye and it didn't give as many and more related image search results as Google's search by image. But unfortunately I still don't see a way to pass an image URL parameter to their Custom Search API. Did you get any leads on that?

Comment: No, there does not seem to be any way of doing that, currently.

Comment: OK thanks. I guess I will use the direct URL (http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?site=search&image_url={Image URL}) for now.

Comment: I think it's not strictly legal if you are making automated calls to this URL. But I'm no expert. Use your best judgement :)

Comment: Perhaps it's okay if you do not intend to scrape the data on the resulting page... that is, if you just intend to show it as it is, then it should be ok

Comment: That's precisely what I will be doing; I will simply format a hyperlink on a webpage that opens up a new tab for the user to go directly to the Google results...until I can grab that type of information from their API :)

Comment: Is there a solution for this right now? . i need to do a reverse image search using google custom search API .

Comment: Working link to TinEye API https://services.tineye.com/TinEyeAPI

Answer (score 0):

Would you need a simple result?
If you are, you can use Vision API of Google.
This is very simple.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/

You can try on the top.

First, access the URL.
Second, upload your image file on the "Try API"
Third, click "JSON" tab menu on the result.

You can be seen JSON about similar images.