# Custom search engine api search by image

Tags: google-custom-search, google-image-search

I am using google custom search engine api,and what i am looking for is,is there any way to do image search by uploading or dragging and dropping an image .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try any coding yet ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Custom Search API Search Image by Image URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591768/google-custom-search-api-search-image-by-image-url)

Comment: i have already done it ,and it's absolutely working normally with search by text,for example if i type 'hello' then it searches the entire web for 'hello' and also any image with 'hello',so that's not an issue,the point is whether i can do it by uploading or dragging and dropping like in actual google image search.                  And yeah i have coded and couldn't find a solution ,that's why asking.